# ms-access linking each checkbox(true/false column) to run a individual code in forms

Tags: forms, vba, checkbox, ms-access-2010

New Edition June 2, 2017

I'm creating a database for a preventative maintenance program for the equipment in my facility. We have about 70 different machines with individuals preventative maintenance instructions, and I've been able to create tables for machines with the instructions attached to them by using forms that will update the database. I created a main form that will filter which PM needs to be done based on the date that is searched that will filter through the machines in the database, access does this fine. The problem I'm currently having trouble with is finding a way to add checkboxes to this main form, and print off only the ones that are selected with a button. The plan we have is to have the mechanics to be able to print off the PM instructions, and use the print off to update the database. Is there a way this can be done with checkboxes or optionboxes?[Here's a picture of the main form that doesn't have the checkbox field attached to it yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjtts.png)[Here's a picture of the forms that will show the preventative maintenance instructions that we will be printed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTbkm.png)

Comment: Please read through some of the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) documentation to learn what types of questions can be asked here.  This is not a good question for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague and doesn't provide any insight on what you might have tried (this would actually help us determine what you want to do).  That said, based on what's given:

If you have a single checkbox and want some action to be performed when it is checked/unchecked.

```
Private Sub CheckboxName_Click()
   If CheckboxName.Value = -1 Then
      'Do something
   Else
      'Do something else (Else is optional)
   End If
End Sub
```

If you have multiple checkboxes you want to confirm which are checked and which aren't when a button or something is pushed you use the Controls object to cycle through all the checkboxes.

```
Private Sub ButtonName_Click()
   Dim ctrl as Control
   Dim i as Integer

   For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
      If ctrl.ControlType = acCheckBox and ctrl.Value = -1
          'Do something (e.g., Select Case ctrl.name)
      End If
End Sub
```

Hopefully that at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok, can you look at the edited version of my question to see if that's clearer to understand.